# Rails 5 Create Multiple Records of Same Model in One Form, Unknown Attribute Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I need to make a form that can handle the creation of multiple records of the same model, and submit the information in a way that passes through Rails’ Strong Parameters. On the front-end, I dynamically add two new text fields for puppy name and breed and want to save them all to a form. But I'm having trouble passing the array of puppy name and breed through Strong Params; getting

> unknown attribute ‘puppies’ for Puppy

I think it's something very simple I'm overlooking. Please help generate these puppies!

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag puppies_path do %>
 <%= text_field_tag “puppies[puppies][]puppy[name]” %>
 <%= text_field_tag “puppies[puppies][]puppy[breed]” %>
 <%= submit_tag “Add Puppy” %>
<% end %>
```

which generates these parameters

```
"puppies"=>{"puppies"=>[{"puppy"=>{"name"=>"ribbon", "breed"=>"poodle"}}]}
```

and the Strong Params in the controller

```
class PuppiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @puppies = Puppy.all
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    puppies_array = puppies_params[:puppies].each do |puppy|
                      puppy[:puppy]
                    end
    Puppy.create(puppies_array)
  end 

  def show
    @puppy = Puppy.find(params[:id])
  end  

  private
    def puppies_params
      params.require(:puppies).permit({ 
        puppies: [
          puppy: [
            :name, 
            :breed
          ] 
        ]
      })
    end  
end
```

Any ideas what I’m missing?

Pseudo code of what I want to pass through:

> [(name, breed), (name, breed), (name, breed)]

How can I write it correctly? I'm following this tutorial https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-build-html-inputs-to-submit-an-array-of-hashes-with-a-rails-form-tag-that-work-with-strong-f70a6c03d78e

Comment: Don't you have to pass parameter `params` to the method `puppies_params` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added rest of your controller code, but I am assuming you are using something like: `Puppy.create(puppies_params)`

But since you are nesting the params in your view, you will need to use `Puppy.create(puppies_params[:puppies])` to ensure you are able to pass in the correct array of name and breed into the `create` action.

**Edit**
Since puppies array contains a hash with puppy key, we will need to extract those to get the final array of puppy attributes.

```
def create
  puppies_array = puppies_params[:puppies].collect do |puppy|
                    puppy[:puppy]
                  end
  Puppy.create(puppies_array)
end
```

My comment below has a shorthand for setting puppies array, you can use whichever version looks more readable and understandable to you

Comment: Updated with my controller. Updated with `Puppy.create(puppies_params[:puppies])` but getting error unknown attribute 'puppy' for Puppy now

Comment: Ah.. yes, missed that the array puppy as another key in there, so you will have to use:
`Puppy.create(puppies_params[:puppies].collect(&:values))`

Comment: ok, I think we're getting closer...getting this error

ArgumentError in PuppiesController#create
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my edit above, I used `each` instead of `collect`, I have updated it, can you try again? If it fails, please post the updated controller to see if there is anything is missing

Comment: Updated the controller above. Still getting this error:

ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in PuppiesController#create
unknown attribute 'puppy' for Puppy.

Comment: Don't you have to pass parameter `params` to the method `puppies_params` ?

Comment: @grace you still have `each` in the controller instead of `collect`

Comment: my bad, I thought you meant you used each. Collect just freezes when I click 'add puppy'

Comment: here's my byebug

   10:     puppies_array = puppies_params[:puppies].collect do |puppy|
   11:                       puppy[:puppy]
   12:                     end
   13:     Puppy.create(puppies_array)
   14:     byebug
=> 15:   end 
   16: 
   17:   def show
   18:     @puppy = Puppy.find(params[:id])
   19:   end  
(byebug) puppies_array
[<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"pappy", "breed"=>"mutt"} permitted: true>]

Comment: (byebug) Puppy.create(puppies_array)
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "puppies" ("name", "breed", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "pappy"], ["breed", "mutt"], ["created_at", "2018-10-12 07:06:09.195232"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-12 07:06:09.195232"]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
[#<Puppy id: 28, name: "pappy", breed: "mutt", created_at: "2018-10-12 07:06:09", updated_at: "2018-10-12 07:06:09">]
(byebug)

Comment: Based on this log, it looks like it is able to insert it into the database. Can you check your puppies table to see if you see the records there or not?
You might want to redirect the user to another page after the puppies are saved in database, like to your index page

Comment: Yes, perfect! It's storing multiple puppies into the array. Thank you so much @Chirag!

  Parameters: "puppies"=>{"puppies"=>[{"puppy"=>{"name"=>"trooper", "breed"=>"mutt"}}, {"puppy"=>{"name"=>"tron", "breed"=>"mutt"}}, {"puppy"=>{"name"=>"trix", "breed"=>"mutt"}}]}, "commit"=>"Add Puppy"}

Answer (score 0):

To get to the array of attributes that you want, you can do this:

```
puppies_array = puppies_params[:puppies][:puppy].map{|puppy| puppy.values}
```

This takes the hash `puppies` within puppy params, and takes the array of hashes in `puppy` and then takes just the value part of the hashes in that array.

You'll get your pseudo-code result.

For info, note that `puppy` in the map block has no special significance... it just indicates the instance of the array.  You could just as easily do

```
puppies_array = puppies_params[:puppies][:puppy].map{|some_dog| some_dog.values}
```